# Laravel 5.6 Validation Regex for empty string

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation

I want to check phone string with Validator. The code is above.

```
$rules = [
    'phone' => 'regex:/^09\d{8}$/'
];
$messages = [
    'phone.regex' => 'INVALID_PHONE',
];
```

Test 1:

```
$data = [
    'phone' => 'test'
];
$vali = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);

dd($vali->errors()->first()); // I got "INVALID_PHONE". That's I exactly expected.
```

Test 2:

```
$data = [
    'phone' => ''
];
$vali = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);

dd($vali->errors()->first()); // I got "". I expected it is "INVALID_PHONE"
```

What I missing?

I want to use only regex.

Comment: My fault, simon's right, i misread your requirement

Comment: "$errors->errors()" Like "MessageBag{ #message: [] }"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because it needs to be required as well;

```
$rules = [
    'phone' => 'required|regex:/^09\d{8}$/'
];
```

When you pass an empty string the validation passes because the phone field is not required so because it's empty it does not check the regex. As soon as it's not an empty field it will check the regex pattern

Comment: That's working! Thank you. But I still want to know why regex is not working.

Comment: How is it not working? Is it not working because when you type 0900000000 it still errors or because you need the required param?

Comment: I expect the string like 0900000000
But why empty string is passed

Comment: When you pass an empty string the validation passes because the phone field is not required so because it's empty it does not check the regex. As soon as it's not an empy field it will check the regex pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now I understand !!

Comment: No problem. Glad it now makes sense